# random unscheduled jogging?

Tags: diet, health, jogging

I have a question about running:

1- I do random sessions of jogging and athletic sports (sometimes at night, sometimes 5 sessions in a week, other times i go through a blank month) because i have engagements / work and it is hard for me to stick to a regular agenda for good, am I doing it vainly ? does it have side effects or is it somehow harmful ?

Comment: I removed your second question. SE policy is one question per post, and it wasn't really answerable.

Comment: Are you feeling worn out at the end? Are you getting faster? What is your goal? Do you do it because you like doing it? People have been running for millennia so it's unlikely to be harmful provided you have no health issues. Trying to combine all the studies of the effects of running into a meta-analysis would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

> am I doing it vainly ? does it have side effects or is it somehow harmful ?

No, it is not in vain. Any exercise is better than no exercise, and you should keep doing it whenever you can.

> Also in the morning when i begin a jogging session i feel like an inner body reaction that provokes me to throw up, is it due to something grass i eat at night ?

I don't know what you mean here. Do you eat grass in the evenings?

> and what is the proper diet to prevent this ?

There is no single diet that resolves all your problems. If you have problems with recurring nausea, you should see a doctor.

For now, make sure you don't run for at least a half hour after a meal. And if you still get sick, try eating something else, but keep it healthy.

Comment: i should say "greasy" sorry for confusion

Comment: yes thanks , but i heard from someones that sheduled exercises prepare one's inner organism to receive stimulation from the body to build muscles/ or improve blood circulation at these constant-timed moments you habituate your self to, ... so i wondered !